# debugging swf locally with remote data

Tags: actionscript-3, cross-domain, flash-cs5

I'm trying to debug a swf in Flash Professional CS5.5, by running the debug-> Debug Movie -> In Flash Professional. When I do I get teh Adobe Flash Player Security window. It says you are trying to connect to and the I.P. address of the server (e.g. 203.22.35.101). I've opened the settings and added that I.P. under Advanced->Trusted Location Settings... that doesn't help. 
Does anyone know how to enable it?
btw: If I run -> Control -> Test Movie -> In Flash Professional it works fine, but then I can't debug.

Comment: I don't know how to answer, except, have you checked for breakpoints that may be interrupting your code?

Answer (score 2):

Embedded debugger is not very convenient. Try [arthropod](http://arthropod.stopp.se/index2.php/?page_id=3) or other debugger. This will solve your problem with debug.